# Explanation of derivation(The Mann-Whitney statistic)

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, proof

Suppose that the X’s are a sample from F and the Y ’s a sample from G, and
consider estimating, as a measure of the effect of the treatment,$$π = P(X < Y )$$

where X and Y are independently distributed with distribution functions F and G,
respectively. The value π is the probability that an observation from the distribution
F is smaller than an independent observation from the distribution G.

An estimate of π can
be obtained by comparing all n values of X to all m values of Y and calculating the proportion of the comparisons for which X was less than Y :

$$π = \frac{1}{mn} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^m Z_{ij}$$ ,where $$ Z_{ij} = \begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $X_i<Y_j$ } \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

To see the relationship of πˆ to the rank sum introduced earlier, we will find it convenient to work with

$$ V_{ij} = \begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $X_{(i)}<Y_{(j)}$ } \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Clearly,$$\sum_{i=1}^m Z_{ij} = \sum_{i=1}^m V_{ij}$$
since the Vi j are just a reordering of the $Z_{ij}$ . Also,

$\sum_{i=1}^m V_{ij}$ = (number of X’s that are less than $Y_{(1)}$)
+ (number of X’s that are less than $Y_{(2)}$)
+ · · ·+ (number of X’s that are less than $Y_{m}$))....

***All step above i have understood. But i can't understand, how do we get the result below***

If the rank of $Y_{(k)}$ in the combined sample is denoted by $R_{yk}$ , then the number of X’s
less than $Y_{(1)}$ is $R_{y1}$ − 1, the number of X’s less than $Y_{(2)}$ is $R_{y2}$ − 2, etc. Therefor:

$$\sum_{i=1}^m V_{ij} = (R_{y1} − 1) + (R_{y2} − 2) + ... + (R_{ym} − m)$$

Can you please explain me the last step? What does it exaclty mean and how did we got this?

Comment: The formula (in words) that follows "Also," and the formula you ask about are *identical* (the latter merely uses a more compact notation as defined in the intervening sentence), yet you say you have understood the former.  What, then, is left to add?

Comment: @whuber I din't understand why do we substract in first parenthesis 1, in second 2 ...in mth parenthesis we subract m.

Comment: How many numbers are less than $Y_{(k)}$ altogether?

Comment: @whuber in Y there are: all values in m - k numbers less then Y(k).

Comment: That's not correct unless the $Y$'s are all larger than the $X$'s.

Comment: @whuber i know, that there are 1,2...k-1 Y's, that are less then Y(k).
And all X's, that are less than Y(k).
Is it correct?

Comment: @whuber For example: we have four X's, that are less than Y(1). So logically, we should add one, in order to become the rank of Y(1) in combined sample. Where am i wrong?

Comment: The $Y$'s are mixed up with the $X$s.  For instance, if they go in the order $YXYXX$ for five values (from smallest to largest), then there are *no* $X$s less than $Y_{(1)}$  and only *one* (not two) $X$s less than $Y_{(2)}$.

Comment: @whuber now i got it, thank you and i apologize for the stupid questions.